# Returning "home" (index.html) in a cordova app using IOS native button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I have an app created via Cordova. "Home" for such an app is not a view but a URI (index.html). all subsequent "views" are in fact other html pages (minisite) all these pages have internal navigation links (hyperlinks).
When opened in IOS, all my pages are in the same "view" of the mainViewController. So there is no going "back" from the IOS's viewpoint, since everything is taking place in the same "view".

The problem is: some of my files link to pdf files. These have no links to return anywhere.

To obtain a back button I did like so:
In Xcode:

opened MainViewController

-inserted button bar and a bar button (called "Titre" and "Home")
-Dragged the bar and the button into MainViewController.h with the
    following result

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *titre;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *home;
```

-Dragged the button into MainViewController.m with the following result (except for the "do something" part:

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender { do something }
```

I have not kept track of all the "do-something"'sI've tried so far but none have worked.
I have even tried something a simple as:

```
 NSLog(@"I just tapped the button!");
```

But nothing renders.
I can see on the Xcode log that the button is clicked, and the sentence is written out, but nothing happens on the emulator.
What am I doing wrong and what is the action that would return the user to "index.html" (my home view for this app)?

Answer (score 0):

In your action handler, you could do something like this:

```
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"index.html"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.I had come across this one already but the "webView" is not recognized because it created on the fly at launch time and thus has no id to be called.

Comment: Is the cordova web view instance part of your interface builder layout? If so, you should be able to get a reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching, I finally found the answer:

```
[self viewDidLoad]
```

So the whole thing is:

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {[self viewDidLoad];}
```

Didn't think it would be so simple!